# How to find the max member in a __m128(F32vec4)

Tags: c, sse, simd

Something like this:

```
_declspec(align(16)) float dens[4];

//Here the code comes. F32vec4 S_START, Pos, _Vector

*((__m128*)dens) = (S_START - Pos) *_Vector;

float steps = max(max(dens[3], dens[2]), max(dens[1], dens[0]));
```

How do I do this directly using SSE?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no easy way to do this. SSE isn't particularly meant for horizontal operations. So you have to shuffle...

Here's one approach:

```
__m128 a = _mm_set_ps(10,9,7,8);

__m128 b = _mm_shuffle_ps(a,a,78);  //  {a,b,c,d} -> {c,d,a,b}
a = _mm_max_ps(a,b);

b = _mm_shuffle_ps(a,a,177);        //  {a,b,c,d} -> {b,a,d,c}
a = _mm_max_ss(a,b);

float out;
_mm_store_ss(&out,a);
```

I note that the final store isn't really supposed to be a store. It's just a hack to get the value into the `float` datatype.

In reality no instruction is needed because `float` types will be stored in the same SSE registers. (It's just that the top 3 values are ignored.)